# Logger fail with Sinatra 1.4.2, Ruby 2.0.0-p195, Passenger 4.0.3 and Rack 1.5.2?

Tags: ruby, logging, sinatra, passenger

This is my config.ru:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'rack/contrib'

root_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)
require File.join(root_dir,'app.rb')

set :environment, :development

log = File.new("log/sinatra.log","a+")
$stdout.reopen(log)
$stderr.reopen(log)
$stderr.sync=true
$stdout.sync=true

run Ivende.new
```

The app.rb:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/reloader'
require 'time'
require 'json'

class Ivende < Sinatra::Application
enable :sessions
set :environment, :development

configure :production do
set :clean_trace,true
end

configure :development do
set :logging, true
end

helpers do
include Rack::Utils

end
require_relative 'models/init'
require_relative 'helpers/init'
require_relative 'routes/init'
end
```

Inside routes I have this file:

```
class Ivende < Sinatra::Application

get "/" do
"HOME PAGE "
logger.info("foooooolanito")
end
end
```

The strange behavior I'm seeing is, when I invoke the main route "/" with the logger line, the explorer shows me the typical passenger error page with the message:

```
An error occurred while starting up the preloader: it did not write a startup response in time.
```

In the sinatra.log file I get:

```
Ready !> socket:
unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.10641/generation-0/backends/preloader.10677 !>
!> Ready !> socket:
unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.10641/generation-0/backends/preloader.10721 !>
!> Ready !> socket:
unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.10641/generation-0/backends/preloader.10774 !>
!> Ready !> socket:
unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.10641/generation-0/backends/preloader.10806 !>
```

Inside the Apache log I get:

```
in 'void
Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::throwPreloaderSpawnException(const
string&, Passenger::SpawnException::ErrorKind,
Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Spawner::BackgroundIOCapturerPtr&, const
DebugDirPtr&)' (SmartSpawner.h:150) in 'std::string
Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::negotiatePreloaderStartup(Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::StartupDetails&)'
(SmartSpawner.h:558) in 'void
Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::startPreloader()'
(SmartSpawner.h:206) in 'virtual
Passenger::ApplicationPool2::ProcessPtr
Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::spawn(const
Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options&)' (SmartSpawner.h:744) in 'void
Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Group::spawnThreadRealMain(const
SpawnerPtr&, const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options&, unsigned
int)' (Implementation.cpp:695)

[ 2013-05-26 01:36:23.7933 10646/7f6ed6a34700
agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:1884 ]: [Client 20] Cannot
checkout session. An error occurred while starting up the preloader:
it did not write a startup response in time. [ 2013-05-26
01:36:24.2287 10646/7f6ed8b49700 Pool2/Spawner.h:739 ]: [App 10874
stdout]  [ 2013-05-26 01:37:54.1869 10646/7f6ed8b49700
Pool2/Implementation.cpp:762 ]: Could not spawn process for group
/home/dd/dev/ivende/wsapi#default: An error occurred while starting up
the preloader: it did not write a startup response in time. in 'void
Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::throwPreloaderSpawnException(const
string&, Passenger::SpawnException::ErrorKind,
Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Spawner::BackgroundIOCapturerPtr&, const
DebugDirPtr&)' (SmartSpawner.h:150) in 'std::string
Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::negotiatePreloaderStartup(Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::StartupDetails&)'
(SmartSpawner.h:558) in 'void
Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::startPreloader()'
(SmartSpawner.h:206) in 'virtual
Passenger::ApplicationPool2::ProcessPtr
Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::spawn(const
Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options&)' (SmartSpawner.h:744) in 'void
Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Group::spawnThreadRealMain(const
SpawnerPtr&, const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options&, unsigned
int)' (Implementation.cpp:695)

[ 2013-05-26 01:37:54.1871 10646/7f6ed6a34700
agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:1884 ]: [Client 20] Cannot
checkout session. An error occurred while starting up the preloader:
it did not write a startup response in time.
```

If I remove these lines from my config.ru:

```
log = File.new("log/sinatra.log","a+") 
$stdout.reopen(log) 
$stderr.reopen(log) 
$stderr.sync=true 
$stdout.sync=true
```

And:

```
logger.info("foooooolanito")
```

Then I see the HOME PAGE text I expect.

This project was migrated from a machine that had Ruby 1.9.3-p327, Passenger 3.0.3, Sinatra 1.3.5, where it worked well.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines in the relevant places:

```
require "logger"

logger = Log.new("log/sinatra.log","a+")
logger.sync = true

logger.info("foooooolanito")
```

Basically your `get '/'` is fine, but you haven't defined `logger` anywhere nor have you `require`d `logger`.

Let me know if you are thinking something else.

Comment: Before upgrading to ruby 2.0.0 this code worked well, even so, i tried your suggestion and shows the typical passenger error page complaining that 'Log' is not defined, but is missing some gem?

Comment: `a+` isn't needed when appending, only `a` is. `a+` means "open the file if it exists and move to the end, create it if it doesn't, and allow read/write access to the file", when only write access is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Comment out this line:

```
$stdout.reopen(log)
```

I think the cause is that Passenger 4 expects to be able to talk to the workers over STDOUT. However I'm not really sure of the best way to solve the Sinatra logging issue now.